# Remove italic within align inside a theorem-like environment

Tags: fonts, align, theorems

Is there any way to remove the italic from the words bits in the code below? That is, change the `\text` output to represent the normal font when an `align` is used inside a `theorem`-like environment.

```
\begin{proposition} 
The memory requirements for the keys are
\begin{align}
  m_{\text{pk}}&= 2r \,\,\,\text{bits}\\
  m_{\text{sk}}&= r
\end{align}
\end{proposition}
```

Comment: Use `\textnormal` instead of `\text`

Comment: Please provide minimal workable example which show your problem, From your code the indices `pk` and `sk` as well word `bits` should be in in the same shape and fonts as main text.

Comment: If (as seems likely) they are fixed mathematical notations you should be using `\mathrm` not `\text` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\text` command uses the font current outside the math formula, in this case italics because you're inside a theorem statement. Use `\textnormal` or `\mathrm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\newcommand{\tsb}[1]{\textnormal{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}
The memory requirements for the keys are
\begin{align}
m_{\tsb{pk}}&= 2r \,\mathrm{bits}\\
m_{\tsb{sk}}&= r
\end{align}
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

[image]